# Find the length of an JSON object

Tags: javascript, json

I have a JSON like the following.
How can I find the length of air in console,

```
console.log (block.number.path[i].air.length);

{ "block": [
    { "number": "36",
      "path": [
          { "air": "[{\"name\":\"0\"},{\"name\":\"1\"},{\"name\":\"2\"}]" },
          { "water": "[{\"name\":\"3\"},{\"name\":\"4\"},{\"name\":\"5\"}]" },
          { "sand": "[{\"name\":\"6\"},{\"username\":\"7\"},{\"name\":\"8\"}]" }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: `air` is a string containing JSON. You have the parse the JSON first to convert it into an array. Also, [there is no such thing as a "JSON object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/). And the "path" to `air` is actually: `obj.block[0].path[i].air`. If I were you, I would fix the JSON to have a proper structure to work with.

Comment: Just like you did? The value of air is a string, not an array.

Comment: Why down vote? Seems stackoverflow is only for experienced, people with small problems will be downvoted.. :(

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`air` itself contains a JSON encoded array, which you have to decode first:

```
// your obj in here
var obj = { "..." : "..." };

// grab the respective length of the "air" attribute
var air = JSON.parse( obj.block[0].path[0].air );
console.log( air.length );
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pLAny/

Comment: At least from the provided code `block` is an array, containing an object, so it needs to be `block[0]` like Ollie mentioned in his answer.

Comment: @t.niese Already corrected that after Felix Kling's comment to the question itself :-)

Answer (score 2):

You can solve this like so:

```
var length = JSON.parse(block.number.path[i].air).length;
console.log(length);
```

Answer (score 1):

It kind of looks like some of that JSON got malformed. "air", "water", and "sand" are all JSON arrays...but parsed out into strings. If you're the one generating the JSON, look into that, because it doesn't seem right. As the other answers point out, it's still solvable in Javascript using `JSON.parse()`, as long as you can be sure your target browsers have that interface (most modern ones).

For any JSON array (anything declared using `[]` brackets) you can check its `.length` property.

Answer (score 1):

Given that `json` is a variable containing your JSON, you can do:

```
json["block"][0]["path"][0]["air"].length
```

Answer (score 0):

Block is an array, so you have to access to the element first:

```
a.block[0].path[0].air.length
```

where `a` is the variable where you are holding the data.